# Unable to use 'dynamic' with Json.Net and Universal Apps

Tags: c#, json.net, win-universal-app

I have the following code

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var url = new Uri("https://someuri/someresource", UriKind.Absolute);
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content) as dynamic;
```

As per what I see when I debug the code, everything is completed successfully; i.e., the above returns the expected JSON, and `json` object has the expected properties... let's assume it is:

```
{ "current_page": 1, "total_pages": 7, "items": [ ... ] }
```

However, when I do `json.current_page`, I get the following exception:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'current_page' and no
>   extension method 'current_page' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Does anyone has an ides on what's going wrong here?

P.S. I tried it with both types of Universal Apps, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

P.S. Same code works with a Console application, but not Universal Apps.

Comment: Did you try the rather more idiomatic `dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);`? It's odd to use `as` *just* to change type inferrence...

Comment: Yes, I tried that too... same issue. I used `as` just for the sake of using `var` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an object with no defined properties on it and you need to parse it first. You can use `System.Web.Helpers.Json` class as follows

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```

As I can see you are using newtonsoft so you can achieve the same using `Parse` as follows

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""current_page"": 1, ""total_pages"": 7}");
Console.WriteLine(d.current_page);
```

Comment: I tried both, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and `JObject.Parse`. My question is specific to Universal Apps. I tried the code in Console application and everything worked as expected. I modified the question to point clarify this.

Comment: `Jobject.Parse` should work similarly irrespective of the platform, I will try for Universal apps and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue and saw that you had opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/696).

This is the answer:

> UWP apps use the PCL259 assembly and it doesn't support dynamic. A dedicated assembly will probably be added in the future but not anytime in the next couple of releases.
>    - **JamesNK**